# Win版Aptana Studio 3でcoffeescriptを開くとエディタで色が付かない

Tags: coffeescript, aptana

Aptana Studio 3をmacとwinに入れているんですが、
coffeescriptの編集をする時に、windowsの環境で色が付かなくてイラッとしてます。

[image: mac版とwin版でのcoffeescriptの表示の違い]

fomatterなのかな？と思ったんですが、そもそもmacの設定でもfomatterの中にcoffeescriptの記述が無く、なんなんだかわかりません。
ちなみにjavascriptはきちんと色がついてます。

わかる方いましたら教えてください。